# Rails sort_by method with two fields one sorted ascending, one sorted descending

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to render a partial that sorts by score, then by name (if multiple players have the same score).

Right now I am using this:

```
<%= render @players.sort_by { |p| [p.scored_vote(current_week), p.last_name] } %>
```

This works, but it is sorting the scores in ascending order, and I would like to sort them in descending order. How can I flip the sort order for the score, but not for name, which I would still like to sort in ascending order?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You question has nothing to do with rendering partials. what you are  interested in is the behaviour of sort_by method .
In btw, this should solve your problem:

`<%= render @players.sort_by { |p| [-p.scored_vote(current_week), p.last_name] } %>`