# Sort_by Ruby, One Descending, One Ascending

Tags: ruby

I have searched for an answer on this to no avail, there is a similar question but the answer did not work in this situation, it sorts on a numeric item. [Similar Question -That did not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19579871/rails-sort-by-method-with-two-fields-one-sorted-ascending-one-sorted-descending) I am trying to use ruby's sort_by to sort one item descending with the other ascending. All I can find is one or the other.

Here is the code:

```
# Primary sort Last Name Descending, with ties broken by sorting Area of interest.
people = people.sort_by { |a| [ a.last_name, a.area_interest]}
```

Any guidance would certainly assist.

Sample data:

### input

- Russell, Logic
- Euler, Graph Theory
- Galois, Abstract Algebra
- Gauss, Number Theory
- Turing, Algorithms
- Galois, Logic

### output

- Turing , Algorithms
- Russell, Logic
- Gauss, Number Theory
- Galois, Abstract Algebra
- Galois, Logic
- Euler, Graph Theory

Comment: Give example input and output please..

Comment: Please link to the similar question.

Comment: I edited my answer to give an example that may better answer a question you asked, and also showed how the expression could be limited to sorting tuples, as in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a custom class that invert the result of `<=>` (including [`Comparable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Comparable.html)).

Wrap the object you want sort descending with the custom class.

Example:

```
class Descending
  include Comparable
  attr :obj

  def initialize(obj)
    @obj = obj
  end
  def <=>(other)
    return -(self.obj <=> other.obj)
  end
end

people = [
  {last_name: 'Russell', area_interest: 'Logic'},
  {last_name: 'Euler', area_interest: 'Graph Theory'},
  {last_name: 'Galois', area_interest: 'Abstract Algebra'},
  {last_name: 'Gauss', area_interest: 'Number Theory'},
  {last_name: 'Turing', area_interest: 'Algorithms'},
  {last_name: 'Galois', area_interest: 'Logic'},
]
puts people.sort_by {|person| [
  Descending.new(person[:last_name]),  # <---------
  person[:area_interest],
]}
```

output:

```
{:last_name=>"Turing", :area_interest=>"Algorithms"}
{:last_name=>"Russell", :area_interest=>"Logic"}
{:last_name=>"Gauss", :area_interest=>"Number Theory"}
{:last_name=>"Galois", :area_interest=>"Abstract Algebra"}
{:last_name=>"Galois", :area_interest=>"Logic"}
{:last_name=>"Euler", :area_interest=>"Graph Theory"}
```

BTW, if the object you want sort descending is a numeric value, you can simply use unary operator `-`:

```
people.sort_by {|person| [-person.age, person.name] }
```

Comment: You are speedy! I will go and try that.

Comment: Should it matter if there are 2 other columns? I can get your code working perfectly as is but when implement it in my code, it is not working as expected.
Code:
http://paste.fedoraproject.org/81568/

CSV:
http://paste.fedoraproject.org/81569/

Comment: And if that is too much to deal with, no worries, you have helped me a lot and I appreciate it.

Comment: @diek, You want to sort by `first_name`, not `last_name`, don't you? Replace `Descending.new(person[:last_name])` with `Descending.new(person[:first_name])`.

Comment: I haven't stopped all week, I missed it. I need a little break. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This is a straightforward way:

```
a = [ ['Russell', 'Logic'],           ['Euler', 'Graph Theory'],
      ['Galois', 'Abstract Algebra'], ['Gauss', 'Number Theory'],
      ['Turing', 'Algorithms'],       ['Galois', 'Logic'] ]

a.sort { |(name1,field1),(name2,field2)|
  (name1 == name2) ? field1 <=> field2 : name2 <=> name1 }
#=> [ ["Turing", "Algorithms"],   ["Russell", "Logic"],
#     ["Gauss", "Number Theory"], ["Galois", "Abstract Algebra"],
#     ["Galois", "Logic"],        ["Euler", "Graph Theory"] ]
```

For multiple fields, sorting on the first in descending order, then on each of the others, in sequence, in ascending order:

```
a = [ %w{a b c}, %w{b a d}, %w{a b d}, %w{b c a}, %w{a b c}, %w{b c b}]
  #=> [["a", "b", "c"], ["b", "a", "d"], ["a", "b", "d"],
  #    ["b", "c", "a"], ["a", "b", "c"], ["b", "c", "b"]] 

a.sort { |e,f| e.first == f.first ? e[1..-1] <=> f[1..-1] : f <=> e }
  #=> [["b", "a", "d"], ["b", "c", "a"], ["b", "c", "b"],
  #    ["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "d"]]
```

Comment: Great! I like your approach. +1. What is this part `e[1..-1] <=> f[1..-1]` doing? Could you explain?

Comment: Thanks, @Arup.  When two of the arrays have the same first element ('Galois'), the tie is broken by comparing the rest of those arrays, using [Array#<=>](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E).

Comment: This is a nice approach as well @Cary, how would it be used if there were 2 other columns? I am still at the learning, and every little bit helps. Thanks.

Comment: Please see the link in my previous comment.  It's well explained in the docs.  If, for any pair of arrays, the first `n (n > 0)` elements (strings) are equal and the n+1 elements are not, the n+1 elements are used to compare the two arrays.(`<=>`, so ascending).

Comment: I missed that. I come from a python background. While I am really liking ruby and the documentation is good, it is not at the level of python.